# Angular routing for admin panel

Tags: angular, e-commerce, angular-routing

I am trying to make an e-commerce admin panel in Angular. I created a layout for the dashboard, header, and side navigation that is working perfectly fine. The components listed on the side nav are displayed correctly on the blank dashboard area but any page inside the component of side navigation, e.g., component 'add-color-stone' inside 'color-stone' components
this the url for color-stone component: http://localhost:4200/general-master/color-stone/

I am expecting the add-color-stone page to open within the blank dashboard area like for now it goes like
http://localhost:4200/add-color-stone
rather than
http://localhost:4200/general-master/color-stone/add-color-stone

folder structure

```
src
 |->app
     |-layouts
          |-blank
          |-full
              |-header
              |-sidenavigation
     |->pages
          |->general-master
                 |->color-stone
                           |->add-color-stone
```

color-stone.component.html

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Color Stone</h3>
        <button class="add-product-button" (click)="navigateToAddColorStone()">Add Product</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

color-stone.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-color-stone',
  templateUrl: './color-stone.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./color-stone.component.scss']
})
export class ColorStoneComponent {

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

    navigateToAddColorStone() {
        this.router.navigate(['../add-color-stone']);
    }

}
```

color-stone.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '../../../material.module';

// icons
import { TablerIconsModule } from 'angular-tabler-icons';
import * as TablerIcons from 'angular-tabler-icons/icons';


import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { ColorStoneRoutes } from './color-stone.routing';
import { AddColorStoneComponent } from './add-color-stone/add-color-stone.component';



// genral master


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(ColorStoneRoutes),
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    TablerIconsModule.pick(TablerIcons),
    MatNativeDateModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
 AddColorStoneComponent,
   
  ],
})
export class ColorStoneModule {}
```

general-master.routing.ts

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ColorStoneComponent } from './color-stone/color-stone.component';
   
// general master



export const GeneralMasterRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      
      {
        path: 'color-stone',
        component: ColorStoneComponent,
      },
     
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: please state clearly actual vs expected behaviour

Comment: @AndrewAllen The URL for color-stone component: http://localhost:4200/general-master/color-stone/

I am expecting the add-color-stone page to open within the blank dashboard area like for now it goes like http://localhost:4200/add-color-stone rather than http://localhost:4200/general-master/color-stone/add-color-stone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the "add-color-stone" page open within the "color-stone" component, you should define nested routes

```
export const ColorStoneRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '', // This will match /general-master/color-stone
        component: ColorStoneComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'add-color-stone', // This will match /general-master/color-stone/add-color-stone
        component: AddColorStoneComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```